# get id's of immediate child divs of a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how do i get the child divs and put it in a array?

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child1"></div>
   <div id="child2"></div>
</div>

var array = $('#parent > div').... (im stuck).
```

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's problem with your code. You are correctly selecting all the child divs of #parent.

Comment: i need to get the id's of the child divs as an array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually there is nothing wrong with your jQuery code. You should wrap it into the `.ready()` callback:

```
$(function(){
   var arr = $('#parent > div');
});
```

If you "really" want a a plain `array` you need to use `.get()`

```
$(function(){
   var arr = $('#parent > div').get();
});
```

For the array of the ID's, as you mentioned in your comment use:

```
var arr = $('#parent > div').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Ref.: [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: i need the array of its ID's.

Comment: @Marting: see third example. `map()` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent").children("div");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wan't the id attributes as an array you can try this:

```
var ids = $.map($('#parent > div'), function(child) { return child.id; });
```

It utilizes the [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function which transforms one array to another.

Answer (score -2):

```
var divs = $('#parent > div')
for(i = 0;i &lt; divs.length; i++)
{
    ...
}
```